# Could not handle node exit code 0 on node.js with kuberneties / docker env

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, unix, kubernetes

I have the following exit code catcher on node.js typescript app  that wrapp with dockerfile on kuberneties  , i am trying to catch why my app is crashing with exit code 0 . without any reason
its happen 1-2 times per day , probably when there are lot of data incomming

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.uncaughtException(1, 'Unexpected Error'));
        process.on('unhandledRejection', exitHandler.unhandledRejection(1, 'Unhandled Promise'));
        process.on('SIGTERM', exitHandler.uncaughtSignal(0, 'SIGTERM'));
        process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.uncaughtSignal(0, 'SIGINT'));
        process.on('SIGFPE', exitHandler.uncaughtSignal(0, 'SIGINT'));
        process.on('exit', exitHandler.uncaughtSignal(100, 'exit'));



    uncaughtSignal: (code, reason) => (signal) => {
                    console.trace()
                    console.log(msg);
                    console.log(reason);
                    attemptGracefulShutdown(code); // will kill the server
                },
```

if I will send process.exit(0) from the code it will catch it
but sometime I have got exit 0 from no where ,

how can I invetigate it ? which tool can I ADD?

my docker command is : CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]  (node dist/main.js)

ps aux print:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.4 334044 39116 ?        Ssl  Feb22   0:00 npm
root        34  0.0  0.0  16792  1288 ?        S    Feb22   0:00 sh -c node dist/main.js
root        35  0.0  1.0 411580 88240 ?        Sl   Feb22   0:41 node dist/main.js
root        51  0.0  0.0  16784  1292 pts/0    Ss   09:19   0:00 sh -c clear; (bash || ash || sh)
root        59  0.0  0.0  16784   212 pts/0    S    09:19   0:00 sh -c clear; (bash || ash || sh)
root        60  0.0  0.0  26748  3596 pts/0    S    09:19   0:00 bash
root        67  0.0  0.0  46700  3048 pts/0    R+   09:59   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: "Exit code 0" generally means your program completed successfully.  It's possible none of the things you trap happen, it just got to the end of `main.js` and finished.

Comment: @DavidMaze hi , but how ? this is an express http server thats already up 
there is no place that close it , and i have. logs in all place, and the hrad thing is that it cant be reproduce because its happen sometimes